# Thread 1 : Program Received Signal "SIGABRT" iOS

Tags: ios

I've been working on this (admitted simple) application as my very first now. It's a tabbed app but for some reason it crashes when I tap the other tab.

There is no crash exception or reason in the log and all that is displayed is Thread 1 : Program Received Signal "SIGARBT".

I began using Interface Builder but grew tired of it and deleted the files and used loadView instead, but despite cleaning the project, I still get the error. The FirstViewController uses the exact same code and works fine.

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation SecondViewController

-(void)loadView
{
    [self setView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]    applicationFrame]]];
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

 textField = [UITextField alloc];
[textField setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:YES];
[textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
[textField setSpellCheckingType:UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo];
[textField setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 280, 40)];
[[self view] addSubview:textField];

setContextButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[setContextButton setTitle:@"Set" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[setContextButton setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 30, 60, 40)];
[[self view] addSubview:setContextButton];
}
```

Comment: What does the stack look like when the abort happens?

Comment: I don't understand what that means. I'm asking you to post the entire stack trace that shows all function calls up to the abort.

Comment: Could you add code from your AppDelegate where the UITabbarController is created?

Answer (score 0):

I think the line `textField = [UITextField alloc];` is incomplete. You need to call one of the **init** methods on the alloc'd textField.

Assuming your SecondViewController.h has the `UITextField *textField` already defined, try:

```
textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 280, 40)];
```

If you don't have the textField defined *(which may lead to other problems, depending on what the rest of your code looks like)*, try:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 280, 40)];
```